# what is the fundamental group of a torus with $k$ points removed

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I was about to use the Seifert-van Kampen to compute the fundamental group of a torus of genus 2. In the process, I need to know the fundamental group of a torus (of genus one) with a hole removed. is there an obvious deformation retraction ? (I don't see it ... ) In general : How can I find the fundamental group of a torus with $k$ holes removed ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: Draw the torus as a square with opposite sides identified. If I remove one point in the interior of a convex polygon, what is the obvious deformation retraction to the boundary?

Comment: Exactly, the fundamental group of of a torus is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and the fundamental group of a torus with a hole is $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @PVAL sorry to repeat your answer, I was fiddling around with my picture and did not notice your post. Hopefully mine will complement yours =)

Answer (score 3):

To figure out the Torus with a point removed, you might try drawing the torus as a rectangle with opposite edges "glued" in appropriate ways:

[image]